# Recursion ( No return still works)

Tags: c++

I was trying to write a function which will take an integer and return it's factorial. I used c++ language.
The actual code should be:

```
    int f(int x)
{
    if(x==0) 
        return 1;
     else if(x>=1)    
        return x=x*f(x-1);
    else
        return 1;
}
```

This is correct form. **But,**

```
int f(int x)
{
   if(x>1)
      x=x*f(x-1);
}
```

this also works even I didn't mentioned any 'return'. Also when the recursion goes to base case, there is nothing to return!
So, how does it works actually ? :o

Comment: It doesn't work. It won't compile.

Comment: @nicomp, nah, it may compile.

Comment: What does 'work' mean for you?

Comment: @nicomp It _may compile_ (with a warning), but is undefined behavior.

Comment: It invokes undefined behavior. WIth that you were very *unlucky* it seems to work (because it doesn't).

Comment: @WhozCraig, there is no way in the world it might 'work' with any sane meaning of word 'work;.

Comment: @Sam I have to add that dupe to my list. Great finding!

Comment: If it work, then you're just lucky. Launching the program a second time could simply crash. Or it could format your hard drive, or spit out baby elephants from your computer case. The compiler is LITERALLY permitted to do anything.

Comment: @SergeyA that would be why I said "seems to work" and that "it doesn't". And if that isn't obtuse enough, I honestly couldn't care less.

Comment: This has answers in the way local variables are stored in memory. It is undefined but I think many of you may find this simple example works. Google where 'return' values are taken from.